# How to set button title from multiple value selected in tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uibutton, nsarray

I want to set button title when user select row from table view when user deselect that value from table view also remove from title name.

Here is my code.
I want to select only 2 rows.

```
        UITableViewCell *thisCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    if ([thisCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) 
    {
        if(i<2)
        {
            //thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            [thisCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
            [selectedIndexes addObject:[catarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            [selectedIndexesTag addObject:[idtag objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            [btncat setTitle:[catarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]     
            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alert= [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error"   
            message:@"User Can only Select two values" delegate:self 
            cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

            [alert show];
        }

    }
    else
    {
        //thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [thisCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
        [selectedIndexes removeObject:[catarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [selectedIndexesTag removeObject:[idtag objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        i--;
    }
```

Comment: which value you want to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
UITableViewCell *thisCell = [tablename cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSMutableArray *selectedIndexes=nil;
    if ([thisCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    {
        if([selectedIndexes count]>2)
        {
               //alert view
        }
        else
        {
            [thisCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
             [selectedIndexes addObject:[catarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            [selectedIndexesTag addObject:[idtag objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        }
                }
    else
    {
         [thisCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
        [selectedIndexes removeObject:[catarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [selectedIndexesTag removeObject:[idtag objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


    }
     [btncat setTitle:[selectedIndexes componentsJoinedByString:@","] forState:UIControlStateNormal]
```

Comment: Yes Its working. Thanks ... but how to remove one string that user select and deselect it..

Comment: you remove value from yourarray  and you set tilte last and  accept answer

Comment: In my tableview some random field is checkmark so any solution regarding that??

Comment: i am new in stack overflow. So i do not have point it says minimum 15 points require